# "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" while querying from CloudKit

Tags: fatal-error, cloudkit, unwrap

I'm trying to get the current users first name from CloudKit using the following code:

```
func getUserFirstName() -> String{

    var firstNameFromFunction: String?
    var currentuserID : CKRecordID? 



    container.fetchUserRecordID(completionHandler: {
        userID, error in
        if ((error == nil)) {
            self.currentuserID = userID!

        }
    })

    container.discoverUserInfo(withUserRecordID: currentuserID!, completionHandler: {userInfo, error in

       let firstNameFromFunction = (userInfo!.displayContact?.givenName)!
    })
    return firstNameFromFunction!
}
```

However when executed, the currentUserID is nil, and creating the fatal error. Does anyone know why currentUserID is nil?

Answer (score 0):

Your App must successfully *requestApplicationPermission* for *userDiscoverability* before it can *fetchUserRecordID*.

Comment: Thanks, how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The code to test if a value is nil looks like this. San maybe right with his answer; I would guess it may be nil too if the user isn't logged into his appleID on the device your running it on.

```
if self.currentuserID = userID {
// do something with self.currentuserID (the unwrapped value of userID)
} else {
// do something now that we know userID is nil
}
```